# Need to apply a vba macro to a large number of different excel documents

Tags: excel, vba, permissions

I have a macro that stops users from deleting rows and columns and i need to apply to between 100 and 200 excel workbooks. These sheets will be accessed daily by a large number of users in 2 different offices from a shared drive. Is there a fast way to apply the effects of this macro to all of these books at once?

Comment: Create an addin which contains your code. http://www.ozgrid.com/VBA/excel-add-in-create.htm

Comment: How is the protection being implemented?  Does the code need to be running when the workbooks are open and being edited by your users, or is it a one-time event like protecting the sheet using a password?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible to add code or a module to a workbook programmatically.  [This article](http://vbadud.blogspot.com/2008/10/programmatically-add-macro-to-excel.html) can help you get started.

Also, you'll need to make sure your macro security settings trust access to VB project.  [This article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/282830) explains how to do that.